# Displaying multiple images from scene7 image set on category image

Tags: image, jsp, websphere, e-commerce, websphere-7

I have taken over a site and am looking for some assistance.

The site currently detects if a product has a scene7 image set associated to it, and then adds IS to the code to display the image set.
I am trying to do this for category image as well, if I hardcode _IS (product sku + _ID) the image set is loaded nicely, but obviously any product sku with no image set, the image doesn't load.

This is the code with the _IS hardcoded:

```
flyoutViewer.setAsset("/${catalogEntryDetails.partNumber}_IS");
```

This snippet of code detects whether there is a set or not:

```
var asset = '/' + wc.render.getContextById('ItemDetailsContext').properties.partNumber;
if (data['catalogRecord.exists'] == 1) {
asset += 'IS';
}
```

Am I missing something major? My guess I am, I can dig out more code if necessary.

Help would be appreciated?!